# Equivalent to a "ListBox" in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

You know Visual Studio, that awesome element called "ListBox"? Just a box that would list a bunch of strings.

I am now working with XCode, and I found this class in the interface builder "NSScrollView". It seems to be able to list me a couple strings. It says it got a NSTextView inside, but, how do I access it?

I am not even sure if NSScrollView is the correct solution I need, but if I could simply access the NSTextView inside it, I think it would be enough.

Comment: Probably worth doing a [basic Cocoa tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

As for getting to a text view inside a scroll view, create an Interface Builder outlet (IBOutlet) and connect it to the text view itself, rather than the scroll view.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look there. Also, I don't quite get the *"connect it to the text view itself, rather than the scroll view"* part. Can I really choose?

Comment: Again, it's probably worth doing a [basic Cocoa tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html). This is fundamental stuff.

Comment: Yes, hovering the dragged connection over a control indicates what it'll connect to. In the case of a scrollview-embedded control, hovering the connection somewhere inside the scroll view's content area will show indicate it'll connect to the embedded control. I'm afraid Rob is right - you really need to go through some basic Cocoa tutorials. This is Cocoa 101.

Comment: @RobKeniger Just FYI: That link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

To get to a text view inside a scroll view; you need to select the controller with your outlet defined; click and hold control and then drag the blue connection line from your controller to the top line of the scroll view; then just wait for a blue line to appear; this will then prompt to let you link your outlet to the text view.

Answer (score 0):

Josh's answer above to use NSTableView is correct. For those not that familiar with it, it can seem like a much bigger task than it actually turns out to be. Hopefully this saves people some time.

Rather than fight with `NSTableCellView` assumptions, you can create any type of simple view you want and use auto layout (or even return a simple NSTextView. This is what I did to get more control over layout of my text strings:

```
@interface PreferenceTableViewCell : NSView
@property (nonnull, strong, readonly) NSTextField *tf;
@end

@implementation PreferenceTableViewCell
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        _tf = [NSTextField labelWithString:@""];
        _ tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _tf.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        [self addSubview:_tf];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[_tf]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tf)]];
        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Then put this whereever you need the list of strings (or controls, or whatever):

```
_tv = [NSTableView new];
_tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_tv.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
_tv.focusRingType = NSFocusRingTypeNone;
_tv.delegate = self;
_tv.dataSource = self;
_tv.rowHeight = 40; // Use this to adjust the height of your cell or do it in cell.
_tv.headerView = nil;
_tv.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular;
_tv.allowsColumnReordering = NO;
_tv.allowsColumnResizing = NO;
_tv.allowsEmptySelection = NO;
_tv.allowsTypeSelect = NO;
_tv.gridStyleMask = NSTableViewGridNone;
[panel addSubview:_tv];

// TableView Column
NSTableColumn *col1 = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"c1"];
col1.resizingMask = NSTableColumnAutoresizingMask;
[_tv addTableColumn:col1];
```

Then in whatever is set as the delegate and datasource for the `NSTableView` add these methods:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tv
{
   return stringArray.count;
}

-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tc row:(NSInteger)row
{
    // This can be ANY NSView based control built as shown above.
    PreferenceTableViewCell *cell = [PreferenceTableViewCell new];
    cell.tf.stringValue = stringArray[row];        
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Code to do whatever when a list item is selected.
}
```

That is basically it for a simple list. See the Apple Docs on NSTableView for more details on how to bind the table to a data sources and more complicated problems.